# concatenate two hex number into string in python

Tags: python-3.5

I tried to convert int into hex and concatenate the hex into a string and write it to files.

but when i do the following:

```
c = ""
c = hex(a) + hex(b)
```

i got error saying

> 'str' object  cannot  be  interpreted as an integer.

How to solve this in python3.5?

Solved:
it turns out a is a string and i want to strip off the leading 0x so a better way that transforms this to plain hex is to do {0:02x}.format(yourHex).

Comment: What are the values ```a``` and ```b```?

Comment: That means `a` and `b` are strings, not integers.

Comment: `a` and `b` should be `integer` because `hex` takes `integer`,  `a=5` , `b=7` , `c=hex(a)+hex(b)`, it'll concatenate the results of `hex` because hex returns `string` so your output will be `0x50x7`.

Comment: they are integers already. but the way i did it won't concatenate them together. it would be a error

Comment: Did you tried the below one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`a` and `b` should be integer because `hex` takes integer and it returns `string` so you can concatenate the output of those two `hex()`.

```
a = 5
b = 7
c = ""
filePath = "C:\\..\\..\\hexFile.txt"    #Path of your file
with open(filePath, "w") as file:
    c = hex(a) + hex(b)
    file.writelines(c)
```

Comment: i need specifically an initialized c as c=" " and c = hex(a) + hex(b) and f.write(c)

Comment: Check it now @user3431800 if you want to use the concatenated value  somewhere by storing it in a variable `c` then you can do it like this.